Calculate discharge from pipe when the headloss is unkown using colebrook white, only D, L, DeltaH, Roughness known
As far as I can tell from the examples I've seen using Colebrook white the headloss is known or Reynolds numbers is known.
But what if you only know pressure difference, height difference and pipe roughness.
My sense is that since the Reynolds numbers is dependent on velocity it's not really something you can iterate? The examples I've seen with iteration of Colebrook White the Reynolds number has been known, or the headloss is known.
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt f}=-2\log_{10}{\left(\frac{3.7D}{\epsilon}+\frac{2.51}{Re\sqrt f}\right)}
$$
I'm aware of an online calculator that does this, and looking at the equation (in the source code) it uses this equation. Which I don't really make any sense of. I suspected it used von Karmans equation, but there is definitly something else going on with that equation.
$$
Q = -\frac{2}{\pi} D_i^{2.5} \sqrt{\frac{L \rho}{2 \Delta P}} \log_{10} \left( \frac{\mu}{1000 \cdot 3.7 D_i} + \frac{2.51 \cdot \text{viscosity}}{D_i^{1.5} \sqrt{\frac{L \rho}{2 \Delta P}}} \right)
$$

Pressure difference is related to flow rate by:
$$\Delta P = \left( \frac {fL}{D}\right) \frac 1 2\rho u^2 $$
And you can express flow velocity $u$ as a function of $Re$.
Do some substitution (or just keep them separate) and you should be able to iterate with a spreadsheet or a solver.
Note: more of an Engineering Stack question, and they are also more open to questions stemming from homework assignments.
Another thing to note on your question: pressure loss is the same as head loss, just in different units.
